# Recommended way to check Google Analytics is running correctly on every page (wordpress)

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, woocommerce, google-analytics-api

I have a Wordpress site that has multiple plugins & that has somehow over time got the same Analytics tracking link (albeit slightly different implementations of it) in a few places on the site.

I want to remove one of them so the site 'touch wood' only uses a single tracking link throughout, is there a website scanning tool or desktop application that will scan an app and help me find each location of this tracking link?

Comment: Are you a) viewing each page individually or are you b) looking to do a crawl? If a) does https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the Google Tag Assistant for Chrome extension